# How to use wild cards in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, wildcard

I'm trying to use wildcards for a query using SQLAlchemy but I'm getting back an empty list.

My code:

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
s = input("Search for a book: ")
q = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE '%\:s\%' OR author LIKE '%\:s\%' OR title LIKE '%\:s\%'", {"s": s}).fetchall()
```

I'm using `\` to escape the quotes that get inserted when the function uses the values of the placeholder variables, if I remove them I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "grey"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE '%'grey'%' OR author LIK...
```

Is there anyway to use wildcards in SQLAlchemy?

I can make this work by using formatted strings instead of placeholders for variables but this will make my code vulnerable against SQL Injections. 
I'm also using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why are you escaping your own parameters, when that's the point of parameterized queries?

Comment: I was trying to escape the quote inserted by the placeholder variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` characters should be part of the parameter you pass in, not the template string, and you shouldn't be manually adding quotes. Let SQLAlchemy do that for you.

Also, there's no need for the template to be an f-string.

For example:

```
s = input("Search for a book: ")
q = db.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE :s OR author LIKE :s OR title LIKE :s",
    {"s": "%" + s + "%"},
).fetchall()
```

Comment: I tried this and it's still returning an empty list...

Comment: Then your predicate does not match, or the table is empty. Note that `LIKE` is case sensitive (in Postgresql).  Also in order to used named placeholders you have to wrap the query in a `text()` construct, if using an `Engine` or a `Connection` directly, instead of a `Session`.

Comment: Oh I forgot to make the search case insensitive! I just used ILIKE instead of LIKE.
Thanks so much for your help!